# How can I iterate over keys of a HashMap and modify the HashMap itself?

Tags: rust

This is what I'm doing:

```
struct Foo {
  m: HashMap<u32, String>
}
fn f(foo: &mut Foo) {
  let keys = Vec::new();
  for k in foo.m
    .into_iter()
    .filter(|(k, v)| v > 1)
    .map(|(k, v)| v) { keys.push(k); }
  for k in keys {
    let v = &foo.m.get(k)?;
    // now I do something with v, which in real
    // application is a struct and I will modify it here
  }
}
```

However, it says something along these lines:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `foo.m`
   --> src/foo.rs:56:24
    |
50  |             .into_iter()
    |              ----------- `foo.m` moved due to this method call
...
56  |             let v = &foo.m.get(k)?;
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

Basically, I'm trying to take the list of necessary keys and copy this list somewhere. Then, iterate over this new already copied list. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this the solution that you are looking for? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5a9e5eb91000daa9762e3e39b12f1c46

Comment: @ÖmerErden I was about to comment the same. The questions marked as duplicates aren't duplicates at all – they can't be solved with `iter_mut()`, while this one can. I'll reopen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`iter_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.iter_mut).
It allows you to iterate over the entries and modify their values.

Looking at your original implementation, it seems like you only want to modify certain entries and leave others as-is, which is something that can be easily achieved with a guard clause during iteration.

If you want your modified map to also only contain these particular keys, you should consume the full original map using `into_iter` and `filter_map`, then collect the tuples into a new map.